# An inequality on signed measures

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu,\nu,\gamma$ be three finite signed measures on a measurable space $(X,\mathcal A )$. Assume that  $\gamma\le\mu$ and $\gamma\le\nu$. Show that
$$\gamma\le\frac12(\mu+\nu-|\mu-\nu|),$$
where $|\mu-\nu|$ is the total variation of $\mu-\nu$.

Comment: Note that the RHS is simply $\max(\mu,\nu)$ which is true given your definition.

Comment: You made a mistake. RHS$\le\min\{\mu,\nu\}$.